# EC: Can you derive Y from X for a public key?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm reading through the EDHOC draft spec and they talk about passing just the X portion of the (ephemeral) public key across in message 1. I've only ever heard of EC public keys (in this case the curve is P-256, if it matters) having both an X and a Y. The implication is, I guess, that you can derive the Y from the X? Is this true? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The implication is, I guess, that you can derive the Y from the X? Is this true?

Well, for each valid $X$ value, there are two possible values for $Y$; it is easy to recover both.

And, for Diffie Hellman, it happens that we don't care which $Y$ value we pick (as the ultimate shared secret doesn't depend on which one); hence we can arbitrarily pick one.

> If so, how?

Well, the underlying relation for P256 is:

$$Y^2 \equiv X^3 + aX + b \pmod p$$

(for constants $a, b, p$).  Given that we know $X$, we can plug in that value and compute $X^3 + aX + b \bmod p$; that gives us the value of $Y^2$ (modulo $p$).  And so, the only thing left to do is perform a modular square root.

And, that turns out to be easy; because $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, a modular square root value by perform by raising the value to the power $(p+1)/4$; hence one of the possible $Y$ values is:

$$Y = (X^3 + aX + b)^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$$

(and, in case you're curious, the other value is $-Y = p-Y$)

One last warning: just because the above formula gives you a $Y$ value doesn't mean that $X$ is a valid coordinate - some (about half) of the $X$ values are illegal, and injecting such a value may lead to an attack.  Fortunately, it is easy to check: take the $X, Y$ values you get and plug them into the relation $Y^2 = X^3 + aX + b \pmod p$ - if the two sides don't agree (modulo $p$), then the original $X$ value was illegal, and you can treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks. I think posting here was a tactical error. I need to know how to do this in Java, and your theoretical answer is correct, but it is not what I need. That's my fault, though, and I thank you for the answer.